# Phonegap Connection plugin Cordova.js included multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've been trying to integrate phone gaps connection plugin to my project. So far i've had no luck.

i've successfully (I think) added the plugin using the CLI.

But it still doesn't work. I cecked the console and apparently än "Uncaught Error: cordova.js included multiple times." is thrown. If i remove the script tag pointing to cordova.js. It isnt loading at all. And of course the console complains about that.

I dont get whats wrong.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.custom.theme.min.css" />
    <title>Skaderapportering</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=loader>
   </div>

   .... SOME APP CODE ...   
    <div id=titleBar><span class=offline></span><span rel=upd></span></div>     

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova_plugins.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.json-2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.md5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.base64.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

I've tried all possible combinations with and without cordova_plugins.js. 
EDIT:
(Phonegap version 3.0.0-0.14.4)

Comment: I see you are loading in js/phonegap.js AND js/cordova.js. Isn't js/phonegap.js just linking to js/cordova.js? Try removing js/phonegap.js and try again, and see if you get the same error. Also check the index.js to see if that is also attempting to load in the cordova.js file.

Comment: That just throws cordova not defined and failed to load resource (network and connection)

Comment: Does cordova_plugins.js rely on cordova.js being loaded in first? Try switching the order of those two around, so that cordova.js is loaded first.

Comment: Also, does your browser debugger tell you where exactly the error is being thrown from? (e.g. the line number and source)

Comment: I fiddled some more. And by exluding cordova_plugins and phonegap. Only using cordova.js No more errors are thrown. Instead some new errors from the plugins are thrown: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined (network.js line: 21) AND Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined (Connection.js line: 25)

Comment: And did you try declaring cordova.js before declaring cordova_plugins? I don't see network.js or Connection.js declared above, should one of the other scripts be loading these in? If you have Google Chrome, load up the web page, then press F12 to bring up developer tools, then click on the 'Resources' tab then from here you should be able to see which scripts are being successfully loaded (and thus which scripts aren't).

Comment: I've done that and all scripts seems to load just fine. Except those two errors. Seem like the function require() and module() aren't defined as they should.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the old plugins will not work with the PhoneGap 3.0.

The new Plugin guide is here:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html

this repo can also help you: 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-2-style-3